# Sqlite query to get unspecified month

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there any sqlite query to get unspecified month.

If i have database entry 
1 January 2014

and next entry

1 December 2014

can I get all months during that period.
i.e. Feb 2014 to Nov 2014

Thanks in advance!!

This is my function which returns me month and year of my all entries

```
public String[] getmonthsmood()
        {
        String result[]=null;
            try
            {
                int i = 0;
                appDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(strmyPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                String selectQuerry = "SELECT distinct strftime('%Y-%m',dateadded) FROM Mood_diary ORDER BY dateadded";
                Cursor cursor = appDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuerry, null);
                // int result=cursor.getCount();
                result = new String[cursor.getCount()];
                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        do
                            {
                                // result.add(cursor.getString(0));
                                result[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                                i++;
                            }
                        while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

In my sqlite database I put a single entry as string and date under Comment and dateadded column.

Comment: What format do these values have?

Comment: Hi - what queries have you tried and why were the results unsatisfactory? What have you googled (so we don't have to duplicate the effort you've already put into solving this)?

Comment: What's wrong with `for (m = 1; m <= 12; m++)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE months(m) AS (
                            VALUES(1)
                            UNION
                            SELECT m+1 FROM months LIMIT 12
                            )
  SELECT y || '-' || m AS yearmonth
    FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN m < 10 THEN '0' || m ELSE m END AS m FROM months),
         (SELECT DISTINCT STRFTIME('%Y', dateadded) AS y FROM Mood_diary)
      WHERE yearmonth >      (SELECT MIN(STRFTIME('%Y-%m', dateadded)) FROM Mood_diary) AND
            yearmonth <      (SELECT MAX(STRFTIME('%Y-%m', dateadded)) FROM Mood_diary) AND
            yearmonth NOT IN (SELECT (STRFTIME('%Y-%m', dateadded)) FROM Mood_diary)
  ORDER BY yearmonth
;
```

Answer (score -1):

To find all dates between two dates :

```
SELECT distinct strftime('%Y-%m',dateadded) FROM Mood_diary WHERE dateadded between '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-01' ORDER BY dateadded;
```

Ensure that the dates you're storing are in the `YYYY-MM-DD` Format. That's what sqlite understands.

Comment: This returns values that do exist in the database.

Comment: okay, so what does the question ask for ? the number of months betwen two dates. I guess I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Correct @CL. I want values which are not exist in database

Comment: I guess you should be adding this to the question. Also, do you want to print the months or the number of months ?

Comment: @ShivamVerma I want months